# Do you get to keep mission weapons after you finish the mission?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am currently doing Medical Mystery: X-Communicate where you have to kill 25 (or is it 15?) enemies with a e-tech gun.

Do you get to keep the mission weapon after the mission?

Comment: Note that Zed *does* give you another e-tech gun for handing that mission in; it is however a slow-firing e-tech pistol instead of the rapid firing e-tech assault rifle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you do not, the weapon is turned in and you lose it from your inventory.

However, if it's a good gun, just hold on to it until you find a better one and then hand the mission in.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have gotten all the kills Zed asks you to do with the e-tech rifle you get from killing Doc Mercy, you can keep the assault rifle and use it only until you either hand in the quest to Zed, or exit the game.

If you hand in the quest, Zed takes the rifle and gives you an e-tech pistol that is usually pretty useless.

If you have gotten to the point where "turn in" is an option, and you exit your current game session (either to join a friend or just to stop playing for the day/night) the assault rifle will disappear from your inventory and be gone forever.